# pass object to WebMethod with Dictionary<string, int> paramter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, json.net

i have this error 
Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]\u0027","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException

when i pass array to WebMethod with Dictionary

Comment: are you trying to pass Dictionary<String,int> object in parameter of webmehtod/webapi project??

Comment: no i make forloop create new object in forloop to push it in array and make JSON.stringify(array) but get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If it is a webmethod of webapi then you cannot pass list or dictionary kind of objects to methods, you will be only suppose to pass the string parameter, to pass this objects you need to serialize them into string and then you can deserialize them back to your list or dictionary object using that string.

Webmethod consuming code:

```
Dictionary<string,int> objstring = new Dictionary<string,int>
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedstring = serializer.Serialize(objstring);
```

and then pass the serializedstring in parameter.

Do the same while deserializing just call deserialize method from serializer object in webapi method.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i want to pass Dictionary to  WebMethod via json function   [WebMethod]
    public string save(Dictionary<string, int> para)
    {       
        
    }